# @Inject in filter doesn't work

Tags: dependency-injection, java-ee-6, servlet-filters, cdi, jboss-weld

As far as I know, CDI should work in filters, but I can't get it to work for me. Code looks like the following:

```
@WebFilter(filterName="authFilter",servletNames={"Faces Servlet"})
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

    @Inject UserBean userBean;

    public AuthFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        userBean.doSomething(); // Causes NullPointerException
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

UserBean.class

```
@Stateless
public class UserBean extends JPABean{
// Omitted
}
```

CDI is enabled, and injection works if I do it in manually via InitialContext.doLookup() or in a Servlet, like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyServlet", urlPatterns = {"/MyPage"})
@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed={"somerole"}))
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject private UserBean userBean;

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        userBean.doStuff(); // Works
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
}
```

Does not CDI work in Filters? In that case, why not? If it should, what could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: What container? JBoss AS 6 has a very simliar bug. Does it work if you just use `@EJB`?

Comment: JBoss AS 6 indeed... @EJB would probably work. Very annoying, I just did a manual inject via InitialContext in the end, but good to know the reason.

Answer (score 3):

In this example I inject a CODI @ViewAccessScoped bean (RegisterView) into a filter, set a property in the bean and navigate to a view which uses the bean. When the page loads I see the username set to "fred". This also works with @SessionScoped (but not @RequestScoped or @ViewScoped). I think dynamic injection is required for thread safety because there is only one instance of the filter in the web container and hence all instance variables.

The problem this is solving is that Faces Servlet hasn't run when the filter executes so there is no FacesContext. The clever work done by getFacesContext() I have lifted straight from this [blog](http://www.thoughtsabout.net/blog/archives/000033.html) from 2004, I don't know who it was written by and there has been no content added for some years, but if anyone knows let me know! Maybe it was BalusC in his
younger days. It uses a static inner class to access the protected FacesServlet#setCurrentInstance() method.

It doesn't work if you use response.sendRedirect().

```
package uk.co.myco.jsfbeans.helper;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.faces.FactoryFinder;
import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory;
import javax.faces.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import javax.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleFactory;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import uk.co.sportquest.entities.User;
import uk.co.sportquest.general.BaseClass;
import uk.co.sportquest.general.Log;
import uk.co.sportquest.jsfbeans.RegisterView;

/*
 * @author Brendan Healey
 * 
 * http://www.thoughtsabout.net/blog/archives/000033.html
 * 
 */

@WebFilter(filterName = "SocialAuthFilter", urlPatterns = {"/pages/socialAuthFilter.xhtml"},
dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.INCLUDE})
public class SocialAuthFilter extends BaseClass implements Filter {

    @Inject
    private Instance<RegisterView> rvDynamic;

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        servletContext = filterConfig.getServletContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        Log.log("testFilter: " + request.getPathInfo());

        FacesContext ctx = getFacesContext(req, res);

        RegisterView registerView;
        registerView = rvDynamic.get();

        User user = new User();
        user.setUserName("fred");
        registerView.setInputUser(user);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/pages/register.xhtml");

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    private abstract static class InnerFacesContext extends FacesContext {

        protected static void setFacesContextAsCurrentInstance(FacesContext facesContext) {
            FacesContext.setCurrentInstance(facesContext);
        }
    }

    private FacesContext getFacesContext(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
        // Try to get it first  
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        if (facesContext != null) {
            return facesContext;
        }

        FacesContextFactory contextFactory = (FacesContextFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.FACES_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
        LifecycleFactory lifecycleFactory = (LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY);
        Lifecycle lifecycle = lifecycleFactory.getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE);

        // Either set a private member servletContext = filterConfig.getServletContext(); 
        // in you filter init() method or set it here like this:
        // ServletContext servletContext = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getServletContext();
        // Note that the above line would fail if you are using any other protocol than http

        // Doesn't set this instance as the current instance of FacesContext.getCurrentInstance 
        facesContext = contextFactory.getFacesContext(servletContext, request, response, lifecycle);

        // Set using our inner class
        InnerFacesContext.setFacesContextAsCurrentInstance(facesContext);

        // set a new viewRoot, otherwise context.getViewRoot returns null
        UIViewRoot view = facesContext.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(facesContext, "");
        facesContext.setViewRoot(view);

        return facesContext;
    }

}
```